# How can I add one row to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I work with a WinForms app.
I want to add one row to a DataGridView that this row must enter to database.
What event handler must I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `DataGridView` bound to that database? If so, you should be adding and deleting rows in that data source, not in the grid control itself. Try calling the [`AddNew` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addnew.aspx) on the binding source.

If you're using a standalone `DataGridView` that isn't bound to a database, then you can call one of the many overloads of the [`Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb98fxxd.aspx) of the grid control's [`Rows` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out to add a row to the DataGridView:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

If the DataGridView isn't bound to the database, try to bound it or write the data to the database programmatically.